# How do I install the latest version of Next.js with Yarn?

Tags: npm, package, next.js, yarnpkg

```
$ yarn add https://github.com/zeit/next.js.git
yarn add v1.7.0
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
error Can't add "nextjs-project": invalid package version undefined.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

I want the latest code, but for some reason it's not installing.

Answer (score 6):

To install the latest version of NextJS:

`yarn add next@latest`

Answer (score 5):

You can create a new project with the latest version of **Next.js** by running:

```
npx create-next-app@latest
# or
yarn create next-app
# or
pnpm create next-app
```

Check the following link for more details :
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/create-next-app

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add dependency package or clone that project?

If you want to create/ clone that project, use:
`git clone https://github.com/zeit/next.js.git`

If you want to add dependency package, use:
`yarn add next.js`

Comment: I want to add dependency, but want to use the latest version on github. The one in npm does not support optional chaining.

Comment: if you couldn't get the latest/ same version as the github repo has, it seems like zeit team didn't update NextJS version yet to the npm. You can try to use `yarn add package-name@1.2.3` for specific version or `yarn add package-name@tag` for specific tag. If you still can't get what you want, better to ask on Github and wait for them to update the version in npm.

Other way to solve your problem is by using `npm-link`, you clone latest NextJS to your local, and use that local NextJS as your dependency for your primary project.